# Html+jQuery : How movable (drag) content of div?

Tags: jquery, html, drag

I have a parent div which is `150 * 150px` and a child div which is `3000 * 3000px`.

I want move the child inside the parent div, like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmy5u.gif]

How can I do this?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can do that with jquery
`$("#child").draggable({
           containment: 'parent'
        });`